# I want to get Data from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have made this ajax call to get data from view. Now I want to make a new ajax call to get data from this call in a new Ajax call. In short words want to make a new Ajax call on next button which will take data from this Ajax. But I dont know what will its url and how It will get data . Any idea ?

```
function loadMaps(id) {
             var field = { id : id };
            var field1 = { id : id };
            jQuery.ajax('{% url "mapport.maps.product" %}', {
                data : field,
                nextpage : field1,

                success: function(response, status, xhr) {
                    showMaps(response.data)
                     pagination(response.nextpage, response.previouspage,                response.currentpage , response.totalpages,response.previousNum, response.nextNum)


                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: jQuery.ajax syntax with example: [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

Comment: Its single call.I want to get data from this call. What will URL in my new Ajax call ? @Abhi

Comment: Does you view return a object that contains the URL? Then you may use: `success: function(data) { var new_url = data.url; ...<new ajax call with new url here> }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create another function below run it the way you want as follows. I think your english is letting you down here.

```
function loadMaps(id) {
        var field = { id : id };
        var field1 = { id : id };
        jQuery.ajax('{% url "mapport.maps.product" %}', {
            data : field,
            nextpage : field1,

            success: function(response, status, xhr) {
                showMaps(response.data)
                pagination(response.nextpage, response.previouspage,
            response.currentpage , response.totalpages,response.previousNum, response.nextNum)

newAjaxCall(response.data)

            }
        });
    }

function newAjaxCall(dataFromAbove) {

}
```

Comment: I want to go next page without refreshing page . then this function will call onClick() of button ?

Comment: then pass field1 to the next function

Answer (score 0):

Or read a little about promises brother, here is an idea you could use

```
        var firstTask = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        });
        var secondTask= new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        });
        Promise.all([
            firstTask,
            secondTask])
            .then(function(values) {

            // Imagine all your data in one object... 

        });
```

etc